# Many of which as subject

Tags: pronouns

I saw this sentence in a Guardian article about parentship:

> "Parenting is challenging and the only training we get is through our own childhood experiences, many of which it would be preferable not to pass on."

My question is, after the comma in second sentence fragment, there is "many of which" and "it", which pronoun refers to which noun?

It happens to me that there are two subjects or am I wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The *which* in *many of which* is a relative pronoun with *experiences* as its antecedent.

But *it* in your sentence is not a relative pronoun with an antecedent. It doesn't refer back to any noun in the sentence. The *it* here is usually called the *dummy 'it'* or *anticipatory 'it'*.

As *The Oxford Dictionary of English Grammar* (p130) states:

> The *dummy it* has no intrinsic meaning, but plays a role in the grammatical structure of a clause ... .

The *dummy it* is used to fulfil the principle of [end-weight](https://www.thoughtco.com/end-weight-grammar-1690594): the 'heavier' or more important elements of an utterance are placed at its end. You could write:

> Not passing on our own childhood experiences would be preferable.

But a much more likely structure is:

> It would be preferable not to pass on our own childhood experiences.

The use of the *dummy it* to enable such constructions is called [*extraposition*](https://www.thoughtco.com/extraposition-grammar-term-1690626).

So, deconstructing the passage you cite we get:

> Parenting is challenging and the only training we get is through our own childhood experiences. It would be preferable not to pass on many of these experiences.

Comment: Out of curiosity, and because I'm not sure if I am right, would the phrase still work without the pronoun "it"? I see the "it" as a way of focussing our attention, as an emphasizer, but non-essential.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A. I think yours would be an interesting question in its own right. Omitting the _it_  in the Op's text seems more or less acceptable to me. But the extrapolated statement _Many experiences would be preferable not to have_ seems a little more dubious.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: omitting the _it_ forces a passive construction: _many of which would preferably not be passed on_.

Answer (score 0):

The period can be rewritten thus: "It would be preferable not to pass on many of
our own..."

There are two sentences: the first is "It would be preferable"; and the second,
"not to pass on many of our own...".

The second sentence is the subject in this [subordination](http://eslus.com/LESSONS/GRAMMAR/COMBINE/S1.htm#subordination)
relationship. "It" then refers to that whole second sentence ("not to pass on...").

Edit: since my native language is a Romance, the "it" still (after years) feels alien and unecessary, but the grammar concepts apply almost perfectly.

Edit 2: As Shoe pointed out, the same passage may be expressed this way:

```
Not passing on our own childhood experiences would be preferable.
```

evidencing the [subordination](http://eslus.com/LESSONS/GRAMMAR/COMBINE/S1.htm#subordination) relationship: a period with two sentences, the
first of which is the subject.

But while the "it" in

```
It would be preferable not to pass on our own childhood experiences.
```

*doesn't refer back to any noun in the sentence*, it is a
pronoun that acts as subject of "would be preferable". And what would be
preferable?

```
...not to pass on our own childhood experiences.
```

Therefore the "it" is a forward reference to what is to come.

Comment: You don't need to say "edit" every time you improve a contribution. Regular users can see your editing history via the timestamp.

Comment: Sometimes it makes it clearer to whoever parachutes in here. I haven't pointed out all my edits: just the ones I found pivotal.